# Where to break page when printing a page in landscape mode?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I have a list of products and each product have a checkbox like this:

[image]

My mission is to print the selected products (selected by user, so I never know how many there are to print) in landscape mode. For that, I can use CSS, JavaScript, jQuery (any plugins), and PHP.

And the results need to be like this:

[image]

I have a situation because some of the products have a description (or other items) two times longer, and it is printing in a second page :(

MY QUESTIONS:

1. I am using `@media print{ @page {size: landscape} }`, should I use CSS2 or CSS3, or maybe responsive tables? (I need 3 columns if there are 3 products, 2 if there is 1, or else just 1 column).
2. Do you know some algorithm for this situation?
3. IF NOT When should I use a page break when products have too many items (is too long)?

Do you have some advice for this mystery please. I am doing something like this:

```
@media all {
    .page-break { display: none; }
}

@media print {
    .page-break { display: block; page-break-before: always; }
}

<h1>Page Title</h1>
<!-- content block -->
<!-- content block -->
<div class="page-break"></div>
<!-- content block -->
<!-- content block -->
<div class="page-break"></div>
<!-- content block -->
<!-- content -->
```

But when to break page if my column is too long?

Comment: How about if there are more than 3 products? Would it be 3 columns or just 1 in that case?

Comment: if column == 3 -> 1 page(3 coll), if column == 2 -> 1 page(2 coll), if column == 1 -> 1 page(1 coll), if column == 5 -> 2 page(3 coll in first page and 2 col in second page) question is where to do break page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you don't know which products will be selected by the user, you will have to add the page-breaks dynamically using JavaScript, and parse the document each time that the client selects/unselects a product so they still fit in the way you want.

One way of doing it:

- Initially there will be a separator div (with the page break) after each product and it will be hidden.

  ```
  <h1>Page Title</h1>
  <!-- product block -->
  <div class="page-break"></div>
  <!-- product block -->
  <div class="page-break"></div>
  <!-- product block -->
  <div class="page-break"></div>
  <!-- product block -->
  <div class="page-break"></div>
  <!-- product block -->
  <div class="page-break"></div>
  <!-- content -->
  ```
- Every time that the user checks/unchecks one product:

  1. Hide all the visible separators (if any). You could do this by adding/removing a `visible` class using JavaScript. That class would be defined like this:

     ```
     @media all {
         .page-break { display: none; }
     }

     @media print {
         .page-break.visible { display: block; page-break-after: always; }
     }
     ```
  2. Traverse the list of products to see which one is selected.
  3. After each 3 selected elements, get the next separator and add the `visible` class to it.

Here is a simple demo that shows how it would work:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            * { margin:0; padding:0; border:0; }
            .product { width:30%; display:inline-block; }
            .separator { page-break-after:always; display:none; }
            @media print {
                .separator.visible { display: block; page-break-after: always; }
                .product { display:none; }
                .product.visible { display:inline-block; }
            }
        </style>
        <script>
        function recalculateSeparators() {

            var x = 0;      

            // reset the print visibility
            $(".separator").removeClass("visible");
            $(".product").removeClass("visible");

            // traverse the list of products
            $(".product").each(function() {

                // if the checkbox is selected for that product
                if ($(this).find("input:checked").length) {

                    // indicate that the product will be visible for print
                    $(this).addClass("visible");

                    // if it's the third element, make the next separator visible too
                    if (++x % 3 == 0) {
                        $(this).next(".separator").addClass("visible");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="product"><input type="checkbox" onclick="recalculateSeparators()" /> Product A</div>
        <div class="separator"></div>
        <div class="product"><input type="checkbox" onclick="recalculateSeparators()" /> Product B</div>
        <div class="separator"></div>
        <div class="product"><input type="checkbox" onclick="recalculateSeparators()" /> Product C</div>
        <div class="separator"></div>
        <div class="product"><input type="checkbox" onclick="recalculateSeparators()" /> Product D</div>
        <div class="separator"></div>
        <div class="product"><input type="checkbox" onclick="recalculateSeparators()" /> Product E</div>
        <div class="separator"></div>
        <div class="product"><input type="checkbox" onclick="recalculateSeparators()" /> Product F</div>
        <div class="separator"></div>
        <div class="product"><input type="checkbox" onclick="recalculateSeparators()" /> Product G</div>
        <div class="separator"></div>
        <div class="product"><input type="checkbox" onclick="recalculateSeparators()" /> Product H</div>
        <div class="separator"></div>
        <div class="product"><input type="checkbox" onclick="recalculateSeparators()" /> Product I</div>
        <div class="separator"></div>
        <div class="product"><input type="checkbox" onclick="recalculateSeparators()" /> Product J</div>
        <div class="separator"></div>
        <div class="product"><input type="checkbox" onclick="recalculateSeparators()" /> Product K</div>
        <div class="separator"></div>
        <div class="product"><input type="checkbox" onclick="recalculateSeparators()" /> Product L</div>
        <div class="separator"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you very much for your precious time and your help, your solution is very clean and god but it result a 50 % of my problem. Now i don't know where to put <<break page>> if i have ex: 6 items, 3 in first page and 2 on second page and i would like to avoid cutting in half one of tables..  i whose thinking to encapsulate each column in to div(class="column") and then check width of "column" and if it is > then page width i will cutted in some place...do you have some better solutions?

Comment: I don't fully understand your comment. If what you want is to avoid breaking the element into two pages, you could try to use `page-break-inside: avoid;` in the product block. But that won't always work if the element data is too long.